# Searching a string using grep in a range of multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep

Hope title is self-explanatory but I'll still try to be more clear on what I'm trying to do. I am looking for a string "Live message" within my log files. By using simple grep command, I can get this information from all the files inside a folder. The command I'm using is as follows,

```
grep "Live message" *
```

However, since I have log files ranging back to mid-last year, is there a way to define a range using grep to search for this particular string. My log files appear as follows,

```
commLogs.log.2015-11-01
commLogs.log.2015-11-01
commLogs.log.2015-11-01
...
commLogs.log.2016-01-01
commLogs.log.2016-01-02
...
commLogs.log.2016-06-01
commLogs.log.2016-06-02
```

I would like to search for "Live message" within 2016-01-01 - 2016-06-02 range, now writing each file name would be very hard and tidious like this,

```
grep "Live message" commLogs.log.2016-01-01 commLogs.log.2016-01-02 commLogs.log.2016-01-03 ...
```

Is there a better way than this?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: How do you want to give a range by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls * | sed "/2015-06-01/,/2016-06-03/p" -n | xargs grep "Live message"
```

`ls *` is all log file (better sort by date), may be replace on `find -type f -name ...`

`sed "/<BEGIN_REGEX>/,/<END_REGEX>/p" -n` filter all line between BEGIN_REGEX and END_REGEX

`xargs grep "Live message"` is pass all files to grep

Comment: Thanks aropan, it works great ... Thanks for the detailed explanation of each step as well. By the way, just curious, is there a way we could count the number of times "Live message" appears within that particular range?

Comment: Usually you should [avoid parsing the output from ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @rac3b3nn0n add to end (after grep) `| wc -l` this count output lines

Comment: @andlrc I checked but it gives occurrence of String in each file, But I'm more towards the total count of occurrence from all files.

Comment: @aropan Thanks for clarifying, didn't know `grep` would show count for each file :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are fortunate that your dates are stored in YYYY-MM-DD fashion; it allows you to compare dates by comparing strings lexicographically:

```
for f in *; do
    d=${f#commLogs.log.}
    if [[ $d > 2016-01-00 && $d < 2016-06-02 ]]; then
        cat "$f"
    fi
done | grep "Live message"
```

This isn't ideal; it's a bit verbose, and requires running `cat` multiple times. It can be improved by storing file names in an array, which will work as long as the number of matches doesn't grow too big:

```
for f in *; do
    d=${f#commLogs.log.}
    if [[ $d > 2016-01-00 && $d < 2016-06-02 ]]; then
        files+=("$f")
    fi
done
grep "Live message" "${f[@]}"
```

Depending on the range, you may be able to write a suitable pattern to match the range, but it gets tricky since you can only pattern match *strings*, not numeric *ranges*.

```
grep "Live message" commLogs.log.2016-0[1-5]-* commLogs.log.2016-06-0[1-2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the grep statement, I've tried running it however it is (for some reason) missing some log files, like it starts with 2016-01-01 and then jumps to 2016-01-04 whereas I've checked and found "Live Stream" in 02 and 03 log files too.

Comment: Hm. I wonder if `grep` doesn't necessarily search the files in the order presented on the command line.

Comment: Could be, the solution provided by @aropan worked fine